# xmms2: path of current file

Tags: linux

The `current` command of XMMS2 only prints artist, track, duration and such. I would like to know the path of the current file being played.

```
$ xmms2
Welcome to the XMMS2 CLI shell!
Type 'help' to list the available commands and 'exit' (or CTRL-D) to leave the shell.
xmms2> current
Playing: Unknown - Track 01: 06:21 of 07:58
xmms2>
```

According to the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xmms2.1.html#format%20string) there is a `-f <format>` option, but that only supports `position`, `playback_status`, `playtime`, `duration`, `minutes`, `seconds` data to be displayed. Is there any command that I could use to get the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
xmms2 info
```

or

```
xmms2 current -f '${url}'
```